Why do my Python Playwright test work in Firefox but fail in Chromium?
These tests works in Firefox but fail in Chromium:
def test_cnn_sport_page_title(page: Page):
    page.goto('https://www.cnn.com/sport')  
    expect(page).to_have_url('https://www.cnn.com/sport')  
    expect(page).to_have_title(re.compile('Latest'))

def test_cnn_sport_page_football_link_in_header(page: Page): 
    page.goto('https://www.cnn.com/sport')
    expect(page.locator('header').get_by_role('link', name='Football')).to_be_visible()

Title test gives error (Chromium only):
E       PageAssertions.to_have_title with timeout 5000ms
E         - waiting for locator(":root")
E         -   locator resolved to <html>…</html>
E         -   unexpected value ""
E         -   locator resolved to <html>…</html>
E         -   unexpected value ""
E         -   locator resolved to <html>…</html>
E         -   unexpected value ""
E         -   locator resolved to <html>…</html>
E         -   unexpected value ""
E         -   locator resolved to <html>…</html>
E         -   unexpected value ""
E         -   locator resolved to <html>…</html>
E         -   unexpected value ""
E         -   locator resolved to <html>…</html>
E         -   unexpected value ""
E         -   locator resolved to <html>…</html>
E         -   unexpected value ""
E         -   locator resolved to <html>…</html>
E         -   unexpected value ""

Header link test gives (Chromium only):
E     AssertionError: Locator expected to be visible
E     Actual value: <element(s) not found> 
E     Call log:
E     LocatorAssertions.to_be_visible with timeout 5000ms
E       - waiting for locator("header").get_by_role("link", name="Football")


Use traces(https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions#test-options-trace) to see what is happening underneath.

Is this behaviour specific to this page or this application or you face the same issue even when you run it on any public site like google or something.

Also this is important to mention how you are running your tests? Parallel? Headless? Versions? Config details?

What do you see in the error screenshot? Does the page visibly loads in the screenshot?

As a general approach, if you don't find anything else suspicious specific to your page/application, simply adjust the default timeout to accommodate both browsers.
In my experience , Firefox is relatively slower than chrome and this has been from selenium days.
